# "Walking Skeleton" in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests

The expression "walking skeleton" as in: "Little more than a walking skeleton after weeks on the run..." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieter_Dengler#Rescue).

One could say, „marŝanta skeleto” (similar to 'marŝanta mortinto') but it sounds like an anglicism.

Or „vojaĝanta skeleto” from the French, « squelette ambulant », but yet again, this one sounds like a gallicism.

Or even „skeletulo” (https://www.wikiwand.com/eo/Mortulo) but this seems to apply to a fantasy-like dead being. Or „vivanta skeleto”.

Is there an commonly use expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi dirus:

```
marŝanta ostaro
```

Laŭ PIV: *ostaro* estas _La skeleto, rigardata kiel la ĉarpentaĵo de la korpo.

Tio validas en tiu ĉi kunteksto. La ulo ja plu vivas, kvankam lia korpo estis reduktita al ne multe pli ol ostaro.